# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Django configuration file exception

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a sample Django (Python 3.6) application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk via the eb CLI tool. I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-deploy) and all is going good until I get to the YAML Django configuration file.

I'm using Sublime 3 for editing, at first I thought it had some problem with the encoding and/or tabs but then I tried with vim, copy-pasting the exact code from the tutorial and got the same error every time.

My project structure is

```
/
/project
/project/wsgi.py
...
```

```sh
$ cat .ebextensions/django.config
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: project/wsgi.py
```

When I run `eb deploy` I get the next error:

```sh
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - The configuration file .ebextensions/django.config in application version 2.0.0 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning for the next token
found character     '\t' that cannot start any token
 in "<reader>", line 2, column 1:
        aws:elasticbeanstalk:container: ... 
    ^
, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (o) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
```

Comment: It looks like vim [may be betraying you](https://github.com/moraes/config/issues/1#issuecomment-181026784). Have you tried grepping the config file for the tab character after you save it? Apparently JSON is supported as well. You might consider switching to that; I'd say it's a better format anyway (but then in your position I'd be very concerned about working with Python if you can't trust your editors' space/tab handling).

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the exact format as shown in tutorial.

```
option_settings:
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
      WSGIPath: project.wsgi:application
```